# Users Password does not reset after successful login at the console but works fine with SSH

Tags: redhat, login, pam

The title says it all. I have my unsuccessful login attempts set to three. I purposefully fail logging in 2x, then when I SSH into the box successfully the 3rd time my count drops back to zero; exactly what should happen.  But at the console I get failed login attempts EVEN for my successful login attempts.  I am using RHEL 5.6 and no I am not able to upgrade.  Here is my `system-auth` file:

```
auth    required    pam_env.so
auth    required    pam_tally.so onerr=fail deny=3 per_user
auth    sufficient  pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth    requisite   pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth    required    pam_deny.so

account required    pam_unix.so
account required    pam_tally.so
account sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account required    pam_permit.so

password requisite  pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
password sufficient pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password required   pam_deny.so

session  optional   pam_keyinit.co revoke
session  required   pam_limits.so
session  [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session  required   pam_unix.so
```

I have tried adding `reset` after and in place of `per_user` in the
`auth  required  pam_tally.so` field.  Nothing seems to work and I don't know why SSH is working just fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/pam.d/login`?

Comment: You are using pam_tally.  Try pam_tally2 instead - http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_tally2.html

Comment: The `pam.d/sshd` is:`auth    include    system-auth`<br>  `account  required   pam_nologin.so`<br>  `account    include   system-auth`  <br>   `password   include  system-auth`<br>  `session   optional  pam_keyinit.so force revoke`<br>  `session   include  system-auth`<br>  `session  required   pam_loginuid.so`

Comment: I tried pam_tally2 also.

Comment: Let me get you `pam.d/login` but I gotta figure out how to add breaks in here 1st.

Comment: Here's my `pam.d/login:` `auth  [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so  <br/>auth   include   system-auth  <br/>account required   pam_nologin.so  <br/>account  include  system-auth  <br/>password   include   system-auth  <br/>session   required  pam_selinux.so close  <br/>session  optional  pam_keyinit.so force revoke  <br/>session  required  pam_loginuid.so  <br/>session  include  system-auth  <br/>session  required  pam_selinux.so  open  <br/>`

Comment: Go ahead and add those config snippets to the original post. Use a horizontal linebreak if you want to separate them off from your original question. Comments don't work too well for this, as you're discovering.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is quite old I still want to answer to this.

```
account required    pam_tally.so
```

Has be to specified just after auth required pam_tally.so and before pam_unix.so. In your case it should read

```
auth    required    pam_env.so
auth    required    pam_tally.so onerr=fail deny=3 per_user
account required    pam_tally.so
auth    sufficient  pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth    requisite   pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth    required    pam_deny.so

account required    pam_unix.so
account sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account required    pam_permit.so

password requisite  pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
password sufficient pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password required   pam_deny.so

session  optional   pam_keyinit.co revoke
session  required   pam_limits.so
session  [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session  required   pam_unix.so
```